# How do I create a file with 100 random numbers with 15 numbers on each line?

Tags: java

My assignment is to create a new file with 100 random numbers to a new file with 15 numbers on each line. I can get it to print out 100 random numbers, but when I try to get it to print 15 numbers per line, the program never finishes running.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Random100{
   public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
   {
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("random.txt"));
      Random rand = new Random();
      int number, count=0, countTwo=0;
      while(count!=100)
      {
         while(countTwo<=15)
         {
            number=rand.nextInt(100)+1;
            out.print(number);
            count++;
            countTwo++;
         }
         out.println();
      }
      out.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, since you can't divide 100 by 15 evenly, I suspect that's one of your problems.

Comment: @HotLicks http://stackoverflow.com/users/581994/hot-licks?tab=activities is one of my favorite pages on the Internet.  Your comments are amazingly entertaining.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a second count, try the modulo operator `%`. Put the following into your main loop:

```
if (count % 15 == 0) {
    out.println();
}
```

Modulo works a bit like a remainder, so every 15 iterations, this will print a linebreak.

Comment: Just an aside, you (and everyone else) will find your code much, much easier to understand and reason about if you make sure it is indented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

it is because your outer loop is checking for when count equals 100 to stop

change `while(count!=100)` to `while(count<=100)`

you would then need to allow for the inner loop jumping in steps of 15, (you will get 105 random numbers currently)

suggest you add a break if count = 100 in the inner loop

Comment: I suggest you implement mk.'s answer though as it is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset the countTwo to zero after printing 15 numbers. Also since 100 is not a multiple of 15, you need to change you outerwhile condition. Anyway this code will generate 105 numbers in total.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Random100{
   public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
   {
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("random.txt"));
      Random rand = new Random();
      int number, count=0, countTwo=0;
      while(count<100)
      {
         while(countTwo<15)
         {
            number=rand.nextInt(100)+1;
            out.print(number);
            count++;
            countTwo++;
         }
         countTwo = 0;
         out.println();
      }
      out.close();
  }
}
```